# ApacheTomcat - 301 Redirect

Tags: tomcat, redirect

I m using Tomcat server for web application. Please let me know how do i implement 301 redirection code in tomcat server to resolve url conanicalization(Non www to www)?

For Apache server we can place seo friendly 301 redirection code in .htaccess file, But what about in Tomcat server how and where to insert 301 permanent redirection code.

ex: (xyz.com)  TO (www.xyz.com)

TIA

Comment: Have you looked at the rewrite valve? https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks @RichardBrightwell :) But [this](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/4.0/guide.html) solved my problem..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this in your **Servlet**. Set 301 status and new location url into **[HttpServletResponse](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY)**.

```
response.setStatus(301);
response.setHeader("Location", "http://www.example.com/redirect-to-here.html" );
```

Comment: Yes this is also a way @Sundararaj :) Thanks